# How to check all check boxes in Telerik Kendo Grid

Tags: checkbox, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a Kendo Grid with check box column. I want to check all check boxes in the grid and keep it across the pages. I have a method CheckAll(), but it checks only the first page of Kendo Grid. How to check all check boxes by one click on the link or button? My code is here:

```
<div style="text-align:right; font-size: 0.9em;height:28px;position: relative;">

        <span style="float:left;text-align:left;">
            <a href="#" onclick="checkAll();">Check All</a>&nbsp;
            <a href="#" onclick="uncheckAll();">Uncheck All</a>&nbsp;
            <a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-Patient" id="hrefCheckedPatients" href="#" onclick="getChecked();">Export to PDF</a>&nbsp;
            <a href="#" id="lnkPdfDownload" style="display:none;" onclick="$(this).hide();">Download Generated PDF</a>
            <label id="checkedMsg" style="color:red;display:none;"></label>
        </span>

    </div>
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<RunSummary>()
          .Name("CheckedPatients")          
          .DataSource(datasource => datasource
                .Ajax().PageSize(25)        
                .Sort(sort => sort.Add("UniqueId").Ascending())                        
                .Read(read => read.Action("GetRunSummaries", "PatientReport")))
          .Columns(columns =>
              {

                  columns.Bound(c => c.UniqueId).Title(ELSORegistry.Resources.Views.Home.HomeStrings.UniqueId)
                        .ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox'  class='primaryBox' id='#= UniqueId #'>#= UniqueId #</input>");
                  columns.Bound(c => c.RunNo).Title(SharedStrings.Run);
                  columns.Bound(c => c.Birthdate).Title(SharedStrings.Birthdate).Format("{0:g}").Filterable(true);

                  columns.Bound(c => c.customAge).Title(SharedStrings.Age)
                         .Filterable(
                             filterable => filterable
                                 .UI("AgeFilter")
                                 .Extra(false)
                                 .Operators(operators => operators
                                     .ForString(str => str.Clear().IsEqualTo("Is equal to"))
                                     )

                       );

                  columns.Bound(c => c.TimeOn).Title(PatientStrings.DateOn)
                      .Format("{0:g}")
                      .Filterable(true);
                  columns.Bound(c => c.TimeOff).Title(PatientStrings.DateOff)
                      .Format("{0:g}")
                      .Filterable(true);
                  columns.Bound(c => c.DischargedAlive).Title(PatientStrings.DischargedAlive).Filterable(true).ClientTemplate("#= DischargedAlive ? 'Yes' : 'No' #");
                  columns.Bound(c => c.ShowSubmitted).Title(PatientStrings.Submitted).Filterable(true).ClientTemplate("#= ShowSubmitted ? 'Yes' : 'No' #");
                  columns.Bound(c => c.SupportTypeEnum).Title(PatientStrings.SupportType).Filterable(true);//.ClientTemplate("#= SupportType ? 'Yes' : 'No' #");
              }
          )
          .Pageable(p => p.PageSizes(new[] {10, 25, 50, 100}))
          .Sortable()
          .Filterable( )
          .Events( e => e.FilterMenuInit("FilterMenuFuncWithAge") ) // apply x [closing box] on pop up filter box
          )
<script type="text/javascript"> 


    function checkAll() {
        $('input').prop('checked', 'checked');
    }

    function uncheckAll() {
        $('input').removeAttr('checked');
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update `datasource` property not the view.
Try something like that in  `CheckAll` function:

```
var dataSource =('[name]="CheckedPatients"').data('kendoGrid').dataSource;
var data = dataSource.data();
var totalNumber = data.length;

for(var i = 0; i<totalNumber; i++) {
    var currentDataItem = data[i];
    currentDataItem.set("ShowSubmitted", "true");
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
// here all filtered/sorted data as in grid.
var view = dataSource.view();
```

[Here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource) you can read kendo docs about `datasource` object

**UPDATE2**
here solution for get all data from paged datasource:

```
var dataSource = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource;
var filters = dataSource.filter();
var allData = dataSource.data();
var query = new kendo.data.Query(allData);
var data = query.filter(filters).data;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works perfectly. Is there a way to include only those items that remain after filtration?

Comment: Mark as answer that way, it will prevent others to post new answers if isssue already resolved. Check out new update

Comment: Thank you again for your quick and useful answer. But view = dataSource.view() takes only filtered data from the first page of grid. I would like to get all filtered data (from all pages). Is it possible?

Comment: You can achive that by clone `ds` object and remove paging from it

Comment: It seems ds object can't be cloned. Please see the link http://www.telerik.com/forums/data-source-cloning But your experience is probably different :)

Comment: Updated my answer, you can do that without creation new `ds`

Comment: Thank you very much! It works, everything is ok. I only refresh the page between successive filtering. Should I refresh the data object somehow?

Comment: Why you need to refresh page?

Comment: I didn't have to refresh the page, I found the solution. The point was in that an array should be empty in the first line of the function. Everything is ok now, many thanks.

Comment: I forgot to mention that all this code works for me perfectly, but I had to set ServerOperation(false) in the Kendo Grid. It means paging, sorting, filtering and grouping are on the Client side. Because of that, my grid loads very slowly. Is there another solution (to load the grid faster)?

Comment: that way you should impliment that operation on server side and return all data with requred value. Other solutions will produce more bugs than profit